# Reactjs this.props.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple message app that takes the users name, and a message, then the messages are passed down and displayed in another component.  In the component that should display the messages I'm getting an error saying `this.props.messages.map is not a function`.

Here is my code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-pasteur-nz32o

And here is my actual code:

Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Messages from "./Messages";
import Input from "./Input";

export default class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: {
        user: [],
        message: []
      }
    };
  }

  updateMessage(message, sender) {
    this.setState({
      messages: [...this.state.messages, { user: sender, message: message }]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Messages messages={this.state.messages} />
        <Input
            updateMessage={(message, sender) =>
            this.updateMessage(message, sender)
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is where the messages should be displayed (and also where I am getting the error):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Messages extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.messages.map(message => {
      return (
        <div>
          {message.user}: {message.maessage}
        </div>
     );
    });
  }
}
```

Any ideas what could be causing my error?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messages` is initialized as an object in state. If you want to `map` over it, it should be an array. So rather than this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: {
        user: [],
        message: []
      }
    };
  }
```

You'll, want this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      messages: [
        {
          user: [],
          message: []
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense.  I'll give you the checkmark after the time limit runs up.  Thanks!

Comment: @Djaenike heads up in your message component you also have a typo: `{message.maessage}` should be `{message.message}`